# How use the filter of django Admin in my apps on my Projects

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

I tried to find a way to use the filter that gives the Django Admin in my applications, as you know by just adding "list_filter" in admin.py, to enter the Admin, our results can be filtered, I would like know if there are ways to use the same application but in my own projects

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#list-views) and add a filter form to context. It's not like "add one line to admin class" but it does not need much time to do too.

Django has lots of magic in admin site because built-in powerful admin site is one of Django's killer features. So it works out-of-the-box without setting up static url and with only tiny admin module linking your models. But all this magic is not isolated and in most cases cannot be used outside the admin.